# Segmentation fault while modifying move_base

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am currently trying to modify the move_base a bit such that the plan thread runs continuously and not dependent on the executeCB function of the action server.

However, when I try doing this I get Segmentation error due to accessing the mutex of costmap_2d in the makePlan function.

I have been trying to figure out the issue since a few days now, but have no clue whats going wrong.

I am not an expert programmer and new to threads. SO please pardon me if this query sounds naive.

Waiting for your reply.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216188/segmentation-fault-while-modifying-move_base/) by [NiranjanDeshpande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4353/niranjandeshpande/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2015-08-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are accessing a part of memory that doesn't exist. I change move_base the last week.
The code were made to be initialize once, if you try to initialize again without destroy the objects, you will get Segmentation error.

If you don't do that, the problem is the global variables, for example this parameters:
runPlanner_=false;
state_ = PLANNING;
recovery_index_ = 0;
recovery_trigger_ = PLANNING_R;
you need to be careful with that.
Most important, any time you want acess something of the planner_costmap_ros_ or  controller_costmap_ros_, you need to do

```
planner_costmap_ros_->stop();
        controller_costmap_ros_->stop();
```

or pause (`planner_costmap_ros_->pause();`) depending what you want and then do `planner_costmap_ros_->start();` to free the mutex.

They use the mutex to have threads, and to limit acess to objects that multiple threads try do acess, is like a traffic light, if is red none can acess, if green, a thread can ask acess and if obtain the acess, the traffic light become red, the thread to something, and then free the object, and turn traffic light to green.

When you see `boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(planner_mutex_); and lock.unlock();` is what happening.
I don't konw if this coment help you anything, but this was my experience.

Good luck, I lost almost two weeks on move_base. 1 week to understand why the segmentation error, the other doing my code.

---

Originally posted by [Raul Gui](https://answers.ros.org/users/14636/raul-gui/) with karma: 66 on 2015-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0